# Can't add server in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

When I want to connect to a server in Microsoft Test Manager I got this error message:

Unable to connect to server 'tfsserver:8282'. Check that the server name is correct and that you have access to the server.

This is Microsoft Test Manager 2010.

I can access tfs server in that url throughout a web browser, using Visual Studio 2010, using Team Explorer 2012.

The TFS server is installed in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standar
The TFS installed version is: 11.0.50727.1 (RTM)
Configured virtual directory is: \tfs
Configured ports are: 8282
Service account: NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
Authentication: NTLSM
Notificacion url: http: //tfsserver:8282/tfs
Server url: http: //localhost:8282/tfs
Web Access url: http:// tfsserver:8282/tfs
Machine name: TFSSERVER

My PC and the server are under a windows domain. My domain user is included in the management console users in TFS.

What can be wrong?

Comment: It cannot connect because MS didn't think it through. It doesn't do https with MS Live Identities and there are no accessible options during configuration.

Answer (score 0):

this is compatibility issue you need

tfs 2010,test manager2010,team explorer2010

or

tfs 2012,test manager2012,team explorer2012

and the second solution for this is to download update patches from Microsoft Website to enable upward or downward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Bilal, I'll check first compatibility issues and then will try with the downloads